# problem refactoring to reactive programming in angular

Tags: angular, reactive-programming

I am trying to refactoring in reactive programming but I have encountered an obstacle. Below I will post the original code and the modified one for refactoring. The problem is that the username is not displayied on the web page. When the page is loaded it displays 'Loading ...' after a few seconds it disappears but is not replaced by the nickname, which it should do according to the template code. What's up wrong?

**ORIGINAL CODE**
**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders , HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

import { User } from '../models/user';
import { tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Car } from '../models/car';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {

    headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'application/json'
    });

    host = 'http://localhost:8080/';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    register(user: User) {

        let params = new HttpParams()
            .set('username', user.username)
            .set('firstname', user.firstName)
            .set('lastname', user.lastName)
            .set('password', user.password)
            .set('email', user.email)

        let options = {headers:this.headers, params:params}    
        return this.http.post(this.host + 'register', options );
    }

    getUser(userId:number){
        let params = new HttpParams().set('userId', String(userId));
        let options = { headers: this.headers, params: params };

        return this.http.get(this.host + 'getUserById', options);
    }

}
```

**user-page.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-page',
  templateUrl: './user-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-page.component.css']
})
export class UserPageComponent implements OnInit {

  user = new User;
  userId:number = null;
  subscriptionUserId;
  subscriptionUser;

  constructor(private userService:UserService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.subscriptionUserId = this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params : ParamMap)=> {  
      this.userId = parseInt(params.get('userId'));
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.subscriptionUser = this.userService.getUser(this.userId).subscribe( data => {

      this.user.firstName = data[0].firstname;
      this.user.lastName = data[0].lastname;
      this.user.username = data[0].username;

    }, error => {
      console.error(error);
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscriptionUserId.unsubscribe();
    this.subscriptionUser.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**user-page.component.html**

```
<body>
    <h2>Welcome to User Page</h2>
    <div class="containerUser">
        <div class="items"><h2 class="sellerUsername"><b>{{user?.username}}</b></h2></div>
        <div class="items"><app-star-rating userId="{{userId}}"></app-star-rating></div>
    </div>
    <app-user-gallery [userId]="userId"></app-user-gallery>
</body>
```

**REFACTORED CODE**
**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders , HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

import { User } from '../models/user';
import { tap, map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Car } from '../models/car';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {

    headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'application/json'
    });

    host = 'http://localhost:8080/';

    user:Observable<User>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    register(user: User) {

        let params = new HttpParams()
            .set('username', user.username)
            .set('firstname', user.firstName)
            .set('lastname', user.lastName)
            .set('password', user.password)
            .set('email', user.email)

        let options = {headers:this.headers, params:params}    
        return this.http.post(this.host + 'register', options );
    }

    getUserById(userId:number){
        let params = new HttpParams().set('userId', String(userId));
        let options = { headers: this.headers, params: params };

        this.user = this.http.get(this.host + 'getUserById', options)
            .pipe(
                map( response => response as User ),
                tap( user => console.log(user) )
            );
    }

}
```

**user-page.component.html**

```
<body>
    <h2>Welcome to User Page</h2>
    <div class="containerUser">
        <div class="items" *ngIf="userService.user | async as user$; else loading">
            <h2 class="sellerUsername"><b>{{user$.username}}</b></h2>
        </div>
        <ng-template #loading>Loading...</ng-template>
        <div class="items"><app-star-rating userId="{{userId}}"></app-star-rating></div>
    </div>
    <app-user-gallery [userId]="userId"></app-user-gallery>
</body>
```

Comment: user is undefined. You do not call getUserById so you do not set the observable.

Comment: `userService.user` may be an issue. There is no `user` property/value set on `userService` set.

Comment: @monogate thanks for reply, I've changed *ngIf with *ngIf="userService.getUserById(userId) | async as user$; else loading" and username is not showed, still 'Loading...' what's up?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky there is 2 services, one is old without reactive programming, one is reactive; read second service

Comment: @monogate I've replaced 'this.user = ' with 'return' in user.service.ts too

Comment: My hot take: Create a property on your component to hold the username value. Assign the username to this property inside the `subscribe` in your `ngOnInit` and then change the `*ngIf` in your template to use the component property. Can write up as an answer if this works. The better way would be to just assign the observable from your service to a property on your component and use the async pipe to handle it in the template - avoid manually subscribing in the component where you can.

Comment: @nclarx Thanks for reply. what you described is what I was doing before refactoring in reactive programming.Your example is right but is not reactive.

Comment: My second suggestion is

Comment: I’ll write up an answer, but can you clarify if your user-page.component.ts has changed in your refactor? Can you also clarify what your definition of reactive is?

Comment: user-page.component.ts has no more effect on the template, simply I've removed 'this.subscriptionUser' code. To undersand what is reactive programming search 'reactive programming angular'. Good luck and have fun! :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should make your refactored template work with the `*ngIf` and `else` syntax you are using in the template.

Check out this Stackblitz which is based on your code that will highlight the pattern you are going for here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nowbcs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Your service should have a method called `getUser()` which returns an `Observable<User>`.

```js
getUser(userId): Observable<User> {
    let params = new HttpParams().set('userId', String(userId));
    let options = { headers: this.headers, params: params };
    return this.http.get(this.host + 'getUserById', options)
        .pipe(
            map((userResponse: User[]) => { // you only need to use map if you need to modify the structure of the response
                 return users[0]; // returns only the first user in the array that you get from the API
            })
        )
}
```

Your component's `ngOnInit()` method should:

```js
    user$: Observable<User>; // define this property on your component

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.user$ = this.userService.getUser();
        // if you need a userId for the `getUser()` then make sure
        // the userId is inside your `.subscribe()` to the route params
    }
```

Your template should look similar to your refactored code:

```html
<body>
    <h2>Welcome to User Page</h2>
    <div class="containerUser">
        <div class="items" *ngIf="(user$ | async) as user; else loading">
            <h2 class="sellerUsername"><b>{{user.username}}</b></h2>
            <app-user-gallery [userId]="user.userId"></app-user-gallery>
            <div class="items">
                <app-star-rating [userId]="user.userId"></app-star-rating></div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <ng-template #loading>Loading...</ng-template>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: When i say about reactive programming I mean to use only Observable . I tried your solution and logged this.user of component, it does not have user's value, it has '(indice) _isScalar source operator project thisArg Valori'.

Comment: Put a console.log inside the map - this will let you see the value returned from the http request in the console. As you say: you want observable all the way which means that the only place you can see the value is inside the ngIf in your template - the async pipe subscribes for you.

Comment: By “inside the ngIf” I mean that you can only access the value of user$ in the scope of the div that has the ngIf.

Comment: Using my code from above, do you get the user object in the template if you put: {{ user | json }} anywhere inside the div which has the ngIf?

Comment: of course but there is not user's value in this.user$

Comment: You can only get the user value from user$ when you subscribe to it. In the template my code subscribed and gets the value using the async pipe. The only other way you can get a value from user$ is by calling .subscribe in the component and then assigning it to a value. My code with the async pipe is the best way to do this reactively - you want to avoid manually subscribing in the component because then you need to worry about unsubscribing - async pipe does it for you.

Comment: Additionally, if you need to transform, loop over data, or whatever. Do this in the map in the service. I saw another question of yours which asks this - I think understanding the structure I have given you here will help you with that as well. Map and prepare your data in the service, hand it to the component as an observable and subscribe to it in the template using the async pipe.

Comment: I understand the pipe's dynamics but it doesen't work. Calling .subscribe I can't do .subscribe( user => this.user$ = user) and I don't want use a simple variable. I post the updated code, can u look it?

Comment: user-page.component.html https://pastebin.com/nr83gy6f user-page.component.ts https://pastebin.com/JGhTzLHn user.service.ts https://pastebin.com/2THiUF5G

Comment: in this case i don't use loops, it is just one record, user's values (firstname, lastaname, username, email) in this case i need just username

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208988/discussion-between-nclarx-and-cane-randagio).